# How to fix this logo in \tiny size?

Tags: fontsize

I wish to design such a logo that works with different font sizes, just like `\LaTeX`.
Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifdefined\fontspec
    \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontspec{LinBiolinum_R.otf}\selectfont}
\else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{fontenc}
    \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}\selectfont}
\fi
\DeclareSymbolFont{PJLupright}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\PJLSigma}{\mathalpha}{PJLupright}{"06}

\providecommand*{\ProjLib}{%
\begingroup%
\PJLlogo@font%
\color{blue!60!cyan}P%
\color{blue!45!cyan}r%
\color{blue!30!cyan}o%
\color{green!70!black}\j%
\kern-0.266em\raisebox{0.56em}{\scalebox{0.4}{\rotatebox{-10}{$\PJLSigma$}}}%
\kern-0.065em%
\color{red!20!yellow}L%
\color{red!40!yellow}i%
\color{red!60!yellow}b%
\endgroup%
}

\providecommand*{\ProjLibText}{%
\begingroup%
\PJLlogo@font%
\color{blue!60!cyan}P%
\color{blue!45!cyan}r%
\color{blue!30!cyan}o%
\color{green!70!black}j%
\color{red!20!yellow}L%
\color{red!40!yellow}i%
\color{red!60!yellow}b%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tiny \ProjLib
\normalsize \ProjLib
\Huge \ProjLib

\tiny \ProjLibText
\normalsize \ProjLibText
\Huge \ProjLibText

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

However, as one can easily see from the picture, the logo seems quite broken in `\tiny` size. (I'm not sure if this is related to behavior of the length unit `em`.) How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use kerning, but to stack the two symbols.

Some comments before presenting my solution.

1. Never use `\fontspec`; rather, define a `\newfontface`.
2. There's no need to waste a symbol font.
3. Using `\textcolor` seems better than throwing several `\color` directives.
4. You can reduce code duplication.
5. Instead of `\providecommand`, use `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

The stacking is obtained with `\ialign`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
  \newfontface{\PJLlogo@font}{LinBiolinum_R.otf}
\else
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}\selectfont}
\fi

\newcommand{\PJLSigmaJ}{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \hidewidth\scalebox{0.4}{\rotatebox{-10}{\usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}\symbol{"06}}}\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern0.2ex}
      \j\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\ProjLib@generic}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \PJLlogo@font
  \textcolor{blue!60!cyan}{P}%
  \textcolor{blue!45!cyan}{r}%
  \textcolor{blue!30!cyan}{o}%
  \textcolor{green!70!black}{#1}%
  \textcolor{red!20!yellow}{L}%
  \textcolor{red!40!yellow}{i}%
  \textcolor{red!60!yellow}{b}%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ProjLib}{\ProjLib@generic{\PJLSigmaJ}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ProjLibText}{\ProjLib@generic{j}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tiny \ProjLib
\normalsize \ProjLib
\Huge \ProjLib

\tiny \ProjLibText
\normalsize \ProjLibText
\Huge \ProjLibText

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stacking?!!  Why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 3):

Use an `\rlap` for the overset.  Then you just have to exactly undo the leftward `\kern` with an equal rightward `\kern`.  That takes care of the proper letter spacing, but as the OP points out, the overset is not consistent at different sizes.

You have two options: try to provide a non-linear kern as I have done in the MWE below or (as I have also done), use an alternate version that takes the ideally kerned `\normalsize` logo and scales it to the proper font size with `\scalerel*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifdefined\fontspec
    \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontspec{LinBiolinum_R.otf}\selectfont}
\else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{fontenc}
    \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}\selectfont}
\fi
\DeclareSymbolFont{PJLupright}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\PJLSigma}{\mathalpha}{PJLupright}{"06}

\providecommand*{\ProjLib}{%
\begingroup%
\PJLlogo@font%
\color{blue!60!cyan}P%
\color{blue!45!cyan}r%
\color{blue!30!cyan}o%
\color{green!70!black}\j%
\kern-.75ex
\kern+.003\dimexpr\f@size\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax
\smash{\rlap{\raisebox{0.56em}{\scalebox{0.4}{%
  \rotatebox{-10}{$\PJLSigma$}}}}}%
\kern+.75ex
\kern-.003\dimexpr\f@size\dimexpr\f@size pt
\color{red!20!yellow}L%
\color{red!40!yellow}i%
\color{red!60!yellow}b%
\endgroup%
}

\providecommand*{\ProjLibText}{%
\begingroup%
\PJLlogo@font%
\color{blue!60!cyan}P%
\color{blue!45!cyan}r%
\color{blue!30!cyan}o%
\color{green!70!black}j%
\color{red!20!yellow}L%
\color{red!40!yellow}i%
\color{red!60!yellow}b%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\altProjLib{\scalerel*{$\normalsize\ProjLib$}{Pj}}
\begin{document}

\tiny \altProjLib
\normalsize \altProjLib
\Huge \altProjLib

\tiny \ProjLib
\normalsize \ProjLib
\Huge \ProjLib

\tiny \ProjLibText
\normalsize \ProjLibText
\Huge \ProjLibText


\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, taking the lead from egreg, one could stack the sigma symbol on the `\j`, here using `\stackengine` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\ifdefined\fontspec
    \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontspec{LinBiolinum_R.otf}\selectfont}
\else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage{fontenc}
    \newcommand{\PJLlogo@font}{\normalfont\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}\selectfont}
\fi
\DeclareSymbolFont{PJLupright}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\PJLSigma}{\mathalpha}{PJLupright}{"06}

\providecommand*{\ProjLib}{%
\begingroup%
\PJLlogo@font%
\color{blue!60!cyan}P%
\color{blue!45!cyan}r%
\color{blue!30!cyan}o%
\color{green!70!black}
\smash{\stackengine{.1ex}{\j}{%
  \scalebox{0.4}{\rotatebox{-10}{$\PJLSigma$}}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%
\color{red!20!yellow}L%
\color{red!40!yellow}i%
\color{red!60!yellow}b%
\endgroup%
}

\providecommand*{\ProjLibText}{%
\begingroup%
\PJLlogo@font%
\color{blue!60!cyan}P%
\color{blue!45!cyan}r%
\color{blue!30!cyan}o%
\color{green!70!black}j%
\color{red!20!yellow}L%
\color{red!40!yellow}i%
\color{red!60!yellow}b%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tiny \ProjLib
\normalsize \ProjLib
\Huge \ProjLib

\tiny \ProjLibText
\normalsize \ProjLibText
\Huge \ProjLibText


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Now the logo is properly aligned like normal text. However, the position of the "Sigma" is still different in `\tiny` size. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Jinwen Please see my revision

Comment: Thanks for your revision! @egreg's solution is simpler and more elegant, but your method is more close to what I expected, both are very helpful to me.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help, @Jinwen